# main.bundle is over 14 mb when i build with aot

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have an angular 4 project with over 50 components, when i build using

```
ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer=true
```

my main.bundle is currently 14mb which i feel is high, also i use angular material design, which when using a loader, kind of lags when i deploy and call an api service, but on development machine the loader is ok,  i dont know if its connected to the fact that the main.bundle is high (14 mb), or its the effect of the loader or material design. Any advice? below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-experimental3",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.7",
    "angular": "^1.7.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-async-await": "^1.1.2",
    "angular-async-local-storage": "^3.1.4",
    "angular-calendar": "0.21.3",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-material-fileupload": "0.0.11",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "0.5.10",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "date-fns": "1.28.5",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "hopscotch": "0.3.1",
    "linqts": "^1.11.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-mat-search-bar": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "ng-material-floating-button": "^0.6.2",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-file-uploader": "^0.1.4",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ng4-file-upload": "^5.1.7",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-quill": "2.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.22.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Angular Deployment docs? https://angular.io/guide/deployment You're probably loading more dependencies then you need. Take a look at `source-map-explorer`

Comment: Holy crap! 14 MB. If you are loading more than a megabyte on initial page load you are doing it wrong. Try bundle splitting and dynamic loading

Comment: @Narm Yes Ive gone through the documentations, and i also ensured i removed all unused dependencies. Still doesnt add up why its up to 14mb.

Comment: @oligofren Okay thanks will check it out!

Comment: @Narm i have used webpack analyzer and 95 % of the size is coming from the src folder, which contains practically more than 50 components.

Comment: @oligofren, i use dynamic components in the application, and still dont understand why i would be getting over 14 mb, after prod with aot. please how do i use bundle splitting?

Comment: you are asking four different questions. that is four different SO threads. big bundles is nothing new for Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16850. you need to find out which packages are using all that space. try a bundle analyzer like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

You should try to analyze with source-map-explorer

- your big modules/components
- why this modules/components are so big (I'm pretty sure because they are using components from your dependencies/external libraries)
- Then you should try to lazy-load as much as you can
- Of course get rid of all dependencies which you don't need